# MAMP Pro 6.1 - Apache server not starting

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I just update the MAMP to the 6.1 version and now it seems to have a problem with the Apache. The problem is I can not launch the project on the browser ( Open and Open In buttons are disabled).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

See the picture below
[mamp pro v6 interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lmOf.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried opening the pages directly with your browser without those buttons? This would help people have an idea of why those buttons are disabled.

Answer (score 11):

i had the same problem, my solution was to choose the new option under "File" > "Reset Apache Modules", after that my Apache was running again ;)

I hope my first stackoverflow answer will help you.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried all the online suggestions but in the end and I reinstalled MAMP.

Comment: I had the same problem and this did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: That worked.  Was driving me crazy.  Thank you!

Comment: Can confirm this still works for the issue in MAMP 6.6.1 on OSX 12.1. Completely silent Apache failures, no logs to suggest a cause and nothing else worked until this. Thank you.

Comment: After “Reset Apache Modules”，click the "Save" button. And it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the Apache server didn't start, because I had, for one of the **Hosts**, some **Additional parameters for <VirtualHost> directive** entries in Apache tab.

Namely, I had `ErrorLog` and
`CustomLog` entries going to my Downloads folder which is now protected by macOS. There's a way to enable it, but I just removed it and the server started.

BTW my problems only started after I was troubleshooting `photolibraryd` memory hog, and I run every possible maintenance script and disabled SIP with `csrutil`. My assumption is that when deleting caches etc, I also removed the "ok" I once gave MAMP Pro to use my Downloads folder.

Comment: Having some entry in Additional parameters for <VirtualHost> directive was the problem for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem! just updated to 6.1 and apache not starting. No Logs, just notification from MAMP - "mamp has stopped the apache server".

Opening pages directly not working - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

**UPDATE:**

i am not sure what exactly happend, but when i went to settings->hosts and clicked some of them for details - "save"button appeared available, so i saved it without any changes (made by me) and now apache server starting and i am able to access webstart page etc.